# Using a js plugin to embed content in react/gatsby component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plugins, gatsby

I'm trying to use a third-party plugin to bring in and embed job listings into a react component but I'm not having much luck. Could anybody shed a little light into why this isn't working?

```
import React from "react"

class CareersEmbed extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://css.zohostatic.com/recruit/embed_careers_site/css/v1.0/embed_jobs.css" type="text/css"/>
        <div className="embed_jobs_head embed_jobs_with_style_1 embed_jobs_with_style">
          <div className="embed_jobs_head2">
            <div className="embed_jobs_head3">
              <div id="rec_job_listing_div"></div>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.zohostatic.com/recruit/embed_careers_site/javascript/v1.0/embed_jobs.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" 
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `rec_embed_js.load({
                  widget_id:"rec_job_listing_div",
                  page_name:"Careers",
                  source:"CareerSite",
                  site:"https://examplesite",
                  empty_job_msg:"No current Openings"
                });
                `
                }}
              ></script>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CareersEmbed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `<Helmet>` component. According to [Gatsby documentation about Helmet](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/), and [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) `<Helmet>` component allows you to insert a few code that will be placed after compilation inside the `<head>` tag.

So, your code should look like something like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

class CareersEmbed extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
    <Helmet>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://css.zohostatic.com/recruit/embed_careers_site/css/v1.0/embed_jobs.css"
        type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://js.zohostatic.com/recruit/embed_careers_site/javascript/v1.0/embed_jobs.js" />
      <script type="text/javascript" async
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `rec_embed_js.load({
                  widget_id:"rec_job_listing_div",
                  page_name:"Careers",
                  source:"CareerSite",
                  site:"https://examplesite",
                  empty_job_msg:"No current Openings"
                });
                `,
          }}/>
    </Helmet>
      <div>
        <div className="embed_jobs_head embed_jobs_with_style_1 embed_jobs_with_style">
          <div className="embed_jobs_head2">
            <div className="embed_jobs_head3">
              <div id="rec_job_listing_div"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CareersEmbed;
```

This is the output from my local machine:

[image: External CSS loaded]

[image: External JS loaded]

Since the needs are to defer the load of the script until the DOM is loaded, you will need to add to something like `gatsby-plugin-load-script` does:

```
// gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // ...
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-load-script',
      options: {
        src: 'https://js.zohostatic.com/recruit/embed_careers_site/javascript/v1.0/embed_jobs.js"',
    onLoad: `() => Sentry.init({dsn:"${process.env.SENTRY_DSN}"})`, // your stuff
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Plugin documentation: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-load-script/

References: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11013

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have tried this but helmet places the scripts in the head, whereas I need them after the targeted div "rec_job_listing_div"

Comment: You can use `async` and `defer` in your `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is one issue I still have in that I am receiving

error  'rec_embed_js' is not defined

Comment: I've updated it. You will need it to bypass using a `componentDidMount()` lifecycle or something similar. You can load the script with `<Helmet>` tag (recommended option) but the stuff to do with the script must await the load of the DOM, so...

Answer (score 0):

I did run into the same issue by trying to add those Job Listings from Zoho too (using Gatsby).

The solution I've found was to adapt this article to our needs:
https://rangen.medium.com/dynamically-load-google-scripts-with-react-and-the-useeffect-hook-3700b908e50f

So in the end it's like this, and loads only on this component:

```
const Careers = () => {
  const [scriptLoaded, setScriptLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const careerScript = document.createElement('script');
    careerScript.src =
      'https://js.zohostatic.com/recruit/embed_careers_site/javascript/v1.0/embed_jobs.js';
    careerScript.addEventListener('load', () => setScriptLoaded(true));
    document.body.appendChild(careerScript);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!scriptLoaded) return;

    rec_embed_js.load({
      widget_id: 'rec_job_listing_div',
      page_name: 'Careers',
      source: 'CareerSite',
      site: 'https://*******.zohorecruit.com',
      empty_job_msg: 'No current Openings',
    });
  }, [scriptLoaded]);

  return (
    <Box px={['0px', '20px']}>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://css.zohostatic.com/recruit/embed_careers_site/css/v1.0/embed_jobs.css"
        type="text/css"
      />
      <div className="embed_jobs_head embed_jobs_with_style_1 embed_jobs_with_style">
        <div className="embed_jobs_head2">
          <div className="embed_jobs_head3">
            <div id="rec_job_listing_div" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
};
```